# Fabric Mac: Not able to generate Fastlane

Tags: fastlane, google-fabric, macos-high-sierra

Recently I updated my Mac OS to High Sierra. After the OS update, the Fabric app is not working properly. Not able to generate the "Fastlane beta".

> OS Details: Mac OS X: macOS High Sierra (10.13.2)
>
> Fabric Details: App Version: 2.6.17 (1288) Fabric Version: 2.78.0

**Environment:**

```
<details><summary>✅ fastlane environment ✅</summary>

### Stack

| Key                         | Value                                           |
| --------------------------- | ----------------------------------------------- |
| OS                          | 10.13.2                                         |
| Ruby                        | 2.2.4                                           |
| Bundler?                    | false                                           |
| Git                         | git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)               |
| Installation Source         | /usr/local/lib/fastlane_lib/bundle/bin/fastlane |
| Host                        | Mac OS X 10.13.2 (17C88)                        |
| Ruby Lib Dir                | /usr/local/lib/fastlane_lib/bundle/lib          |
| OpenSSL Version             | OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016                      |
| Is contained                | false                                           |
| Is homebrew                 | false                                           |
| Is installed via Fabric.app | true                                            |
| Xcode Path                  | /Applications/Xcode 8.3.app/Contents/Developer/ |
| Xcode Version               | 8.3.3                                           |


### System Locale

| Variable | Value       |   |
| -------- | ----------- | - |
| LANG     | en_US.UTF-8 | ✅ |
| LC_ALL   | en_US.UTF-8 | ✅ |
| LANGUAGE | en_US.UTF-8 | ✅ |


### fastlane files:

**No Fastfile found**


**No Appfile found**


### fastlane gems

| Gem      | Version | Update-Status  |
| -------- | ------- | -------------- |
| fastlane | 2.78.0  |  Check failed |


### Loaded fastlane plugins:

**No plugins Loaded**


<details><summary><b>Loaded gems</b></summary>

| Gem                       | Version      |
| ------------------------- | ------------ |
| slack-notifier            | 2.3.2        |
| CFPropertyList            | 2.3.6        |
| claide                    | 1.0.2        |
| colored2                  | 3.1.2        |
| nanaimo                   | 0.2.3        |
| xcodeproj                 | 1.5.4        |
| rouge                     | 2.0.7        |
| xcpretty                  | 0.2.8        |
| terminal-notifier         | 1.8.0        |
| unicode-display_width     | 1.3.0        |
| terminal-table            | 1.8.0        |
| plist                     | 3.4.0        |
| public_suffix             | 2.0.5        |
| addressable               | 2.5.2        |
| multipart-post            | 2.0.0        |
| word_wrap                 | 1.0.0        |
| tty-screen                | 0.6.4        |
| tty-cursor                | 0.5.0        |
| tty-spinner               | 0.8.0        |
| babosa                    | 1.0.2        |
| colored                   | 1.2          |
| highline                  | 1.7.10       |
| commander-fastlane        | 4.4.5        |
| excon                     | 0.60.0       |
| faraday                   | 0.14.0       |
| unf_ext                   | 0.0.7.4      |
| unf                       | 0.1.4        |
| domain_name               | 0.5.20170404 |
| http-cookie               | 1.0.3        |
| faraday-cookie_jar        | 0.0.6        |
| fastimage                 | 2.1.1        |
| gh_inspector              | 1.0.3        |
| json                      | 1.8.1        |
| mini_magick               | 4.5.1        |
| multi_json                | 1.13.1       |
| multi_xml                 | 0.6.0        |
| rubyzip                   | 1.2.1        |
| security                  | 0.1.3        |
| xcpretty-travis-formatter | 1.0.0        |
| dotenv                    | 2.2.1        |
| bundler                   | 1.16.1       |
| faraday_middleware        | 0.12.2       |
| uber                      | 0.1.0        |
| declarative               | 0.0.10       |
| declarative-option        | 0.1.0        |
| representable             | 3.0.4        |
| retriable                 | 3.1.1        |
| mime-types-data           | 3.2016.0521  |
| mime-types                | 3.1          |
| little-plugger            | 1.1.4        |
| logging                   | 2.2.2        |
| jwt                       | 2.1.0        |
| memoist                   | 0.16.0       |
| os                        | 0.9.6        |
| signet                    | 0.8.1        |
| googleauth                | 0.6.2        |
| httpclient                | 2.8.3        |
| google-api-client         | 0.13.6       |
| libxml-ruby               | 3.0.0        |
</details>


*generated on:* **2018-02-01**
</details>
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the issue on this configuration? Thanks in advance.

[image]

**EDIT:**
I have tried the solution given by @Mike but, I couldn't resolve the issue. Please find the Terminal output,

> Last login: Mon Feb  5 16:45:31 on qqvm915 Yuva-M:~ Yuva$ rm -rf
>   ~/.fastlane/bin Yuva-M:~ Yuva$ rm -rf /usr/local/lib/fastlane_lib
>   Yuva-M:~ Yuva$ cd /Users/Yuva/Documents/iOS\
>   Applications/TestApp/TestApp\ App/TestApp\ App\ Dev  Yuva-M:TestApp
>   Dev Yuva$ touch Gemfile Yuva-M:TestApp Dev Yuva$ bundle update
>   Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
>
> Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not
>   fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ Retrying fetcher due to error
>   (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from
>   https://rubygems.org/ Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4):
>   Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from
>   https://rubygems.org/Resolving
>   dependencies............................ Using CFPropertyList 2.3.6
>   Using public_suffix 2.0.5 Using addressable 2.5.2 Fetching atomos
>   0.1.2
>
> Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
>   You can cancel this installation and run:
>
> ```
>   bundle install --path vendor/bundle
> ```
>
> to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your
>   password   and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.
>
> Password:
>
> Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system RubyGems.
>   You can cancel this installation and run:
>
> ```
>   bundle install --path vendor/bundle
> ```
>
> to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your
>   password   and install the bundled gems to RubyGems using sudo.
>
> Password:  Installing atomos 0.1.2 Using babosa 1.0.2 Using bundler
>   1.16.1 Using claide 1.0.2 Using colored 1.2 Using colored2 3.1.2 Using highline 1.7.10 Using commander-fastlane 4.4.5 Using declarative
>   0.0.10 Using declarative-option 0.1.0 Using unf_ext 0.0.7.4 Using unf 0.1.4 Using domain_name 0.5.20170404 Using dotenv 2.2.1 Using excon 0.60.0 Using multipart-post 2.0.0 Using faraday 0.14.0 Using http-cookie 1.0.3 Using faraday-cookie_jar 0.0.6 Using
>   faraday_middleware 0.12.2 Using fastimage 2.1.1 Fetching gh_inspector
>   1.1.1 Installing gh_inspector 1.1.1 Using jwt 2.1.0 Using little-plugger 1.1.4 Using multi_json 1.13.1 Using logging 2.2.2 Using
>   memoist 0.16.0 Using os 0.9.6 Using signet 0.8.1 Using googleauth
>   0.6.2 Using httpclient 2.8.3 Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521 Using mime-types 3.1 Using uber 0.1.0 Using representable 3.0.4 Using
>   retriable 3.1.1 Using google-api-client 0.13.6 Fetching json 2.1.0
>   Installing json 2.1.0 with native extensions Using mini_magick 4.5.1
>   Using multi_xml 0.6.0 Using plist 3.4.0 Using rubyzip 1.2.1 Using
>   security 0.1.3 Using slack-notifier 2.3.2 Using terminal-notifier
>   1.8.0 Using unicode-display_width 1.3.0 Using terminal-table 1.8.0 Using tty-screen 0.6.4 Using tty-cursor 0.5.0 Using tty-spinner 0.8.0
>   Using word_wrap 1.0.0 Using nanaimo 0.2.3 Fetching xcodeproj 1.5.6
>   Installing xcodeproj 1.5.6 Using rouge 2.0.7 Using xcpretty 0.2.8
>   Using xcpretty-travis-formatter 1.0.0 Using fastlane 2.80.0 Bundle
>   updated! Yuva-M:TestApp Dev Yuva$ bundle exec fastlane beta [✔]  
>   [17:10:27]: Could not find fastlane in current directory. Make sure to
>   have your fastlane configuration files inside a folder called
>   "fastlane". Would you like to set fastlane up? (y/n) y [✔] Looking for
>   iOS and Android projects in current directory... [17:10:34]: Created
>   new folder './fastlane'. [17:10:34]: Detected an iOS/macOS project in
>   the current directory: 'TestApp.xcworkspace' [17:10:34]:
>   ----------------------------- [17:10:34]: --- Welcome to fastlane  --- [17:10:34]: ----------------------------- [17:10:34]: fastlane can help you with all kinds of automation for your mobile app [17:10:34]:
>   We recommend automating one task first, and then gradually automating
>   more over time [17:10:34]: What would you like to use fastlane for?
>   1.   Automate screenshots
>   2. ‍✈️  Automate beta distribution to TestFlight
>   3.   Automate App Store distribution
>   4.   Manual setup - manually setup your project to automate your tasks ?

Fastlane folder generated into project directory but, no file were there. I just tried to generate a build from "Fabric" Mac App, still am getting the error (Find the screenshot.) Any guidance? Thanks.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share the error you're seeing?

Comment: Hi @MikeBonnell, This is the error am getting "Unknown fastlane error: invalid option: --crashlytics_path". Can you please help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: Given the permissions errors, you either need to run the commands with sudo or get temporarily elevated permissions on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric. I'd recommend switching from fastlane in Fabric to using it independently. Here's how to do it, [referenced](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/11586) from Felix Krause.

In terminal, run:

`rm -rf ~/.fastlane/bin`
-- This removes the current fastlane installation from your home directory.

`rm -rf /usr/local/lib/fastlane_lib` 
-- This removes the current fastlane installation from your system.)

After, edit your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` and remove any reference to fastlane. We're clearing everything out so that you can set up a fresh install.

Now, navigate to your project directory and run `touch Gemfile`. Add the following content to that file:

`source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "fastlane"`

Save the file and run `bundle update`. Commit both the Gemfile and the Gemfile.lock to version control and from now on, every time you run fastlane, prefix your command using `bundle exec`:
`bundle exec fastlane beta`

Finally, restart the Fabric macOS app and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try and come with the result. Thanks again. :)

Comment: I updated the question with the my queries. Can you please help me on this? Thanks.